# Chrome extension: splitting selection into two search strings

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Creating a context menu chrome extension, to search highlighted text through various systems.

Currently, searches are run by taking highlighted text and adding it to the end of a search URL. For example:

```
{
 var searchstring = info.selectionText;
 chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.intodns.com/"+searchstring})
}
```

The search URL for eNom domain management splits the search term into two parts, SLD and TLD, as follows:

http://www.enom.com/domains/control-panel/default.aspx?sld=DOMAIN&tld=COM

Trying to figure out a way to split the selection text into two parts, sld and tld, then plug each part into the corresponding spot in the search URL.

End result would allow a user to highlight "stackoverflow.com", run the search via context menu, and end up with a new tab on the following url:

http://www.enom.com/domains/control-panel/default.aspx?sld=stackoverflow&tld=com

Comment: So you just want to turn a `searchstring` like "stackoverflow.com" into "stackoverflow" and "com", or "google.co.uk" into "google" and "co.uk"?

Comment: That is the first step, the second step is plugging those two pieces into the search URL

Comment: For a universal detection of TLD it's better to use [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/learn/) and [publicsuffixlist.js](https://github.com/gorhill/publicsuffixlist.js) library: `publicSuffixList.getPublicSuffix('stackoverflow.com')` and `publicSuffixList.getDomain('stackoverflow.com')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to make it more robust; it shouldn't include "www." when it's at the beginning, but if there's a "www." later on for some reason it'll allow it.

```
var searchstring = info.selectionText;

var parts = searchstring.match(/^(?:\w+:\/\/\/?)?(?:www\.)?([^\.]+)\.(.+)/i);

var name = parts[1], com = parts[2];

chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.enom.com/domains/control-panel/default.aspx?sld="+name+"&tld="+com})
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! I am curious, is there a way to make this work if the "www." is included in the selection? This code assumes it will be omitted as it only accounts for one "." . Maybe something to force it to ignore "www." specifically?

Comment: This version returns the following URL when "www.stackoverflow.com" is selected: http://www.enom.com/domains/control-panel/default.aspx?sld=www.s&tld=www

Comment: Same result as last time, it produces "www.s" and "www" for SLD and TLD, respectively. (thank you again for your help)

Comment: I've made a minor change to fix an unrelated issue, but it sounds like the extension just hasn't "refreshed" or whatever?

Comment: Works perfectly so far, tried on www. and https://www. with various TLDs, all registered correctly. I owe you a beer!